# Fail to use WCF service from silverlight application

Tags: wcf

I wrote some WCF service that contain one method.
The method does not get any parameter - but return string.

Try to call this service thru silverlight application - and i get exception about "Cross domain access policy".

I google it and i found that i need to add 'clientaccesspolicy.xml' to the service root ( WCF root application ) - so i did ... and still get back the same exception.

( I'm using .net 4.0 and my service using IIS 7.5 )

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx

You may need crossdomain.xml as well as clientaccesspolicy.xml.

e.g. crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

and clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Also check this link:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx

Double check that the needed files are in the correct path. I once had this problem with a flash-application which broke all the time just because the xml-file was in the wrong directory.